# Logical with count in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Pyspark and I have a problem to solve.

I have a dataframe with 4 columns, being `customers`, `person`, `is_online_store` and `count`:

| customer | PersonId | is_online_store | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| afabd2d2 | 4 | true | 1 |
| afabd2d2 | 8 | true | 2 |
| afabd2d2 | 3 | true | 1 |
| afabd2d2 | 2 | false | 1 |
| afabd2d2 | 4 | false | 1 |

I need to create according to the following rules:

- If `PersonId` count(column) has 1 or + Trues and None False then `Online`
- If `PersonId` count(column) has 1 or + False and None True then `offline`
- If the `PersonId` count(column) has at least 1 False AND 1 True then `Hybrid`

How it should look:

| customer | PersonId | New_Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| afabd2d2 | 4 | Hybrid |
| afabd2d2 | 8 | Online |
| afabd2d2 | 3 | Online |
| afabd2d2 | 2 | Offline |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `customer` + `personId` and use `when` expression to check if all values in `is_online_store` column are `true` / `false` or a mix of the 2, using for example [`bool_and`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#bool_and) function:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.groupBy("customer", "PersonId").agg(
    F.when(F.expr("bool_and(is_online_store)"), "Online")
     .when(F.expr("bool_and(!is_online_store)"), "Offline")
     .otherwise("Hybrid").alias("New_Column")
)

df1.show()
#+--------+--------+----------+
#|customer|PersonId|New_Column|
#+--------+--------+----------+
#|afabd2d2|       2|   Offline|
#|afabd2d2|       8|    Online|
#|afabd2d2|       4|    Hybrid|
#|afabd2d2|       3|    Online|
#+--------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked, I just had to convert the column to Boolean before.

Comment: "When I went up to production, it started giving this error: Undefined function: 'bool_and'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 0"